# How to load many images at the same time?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem loading multiple images at the same time using matlab. Could anybody me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is. Do you just not know how to start, or are you getting errors on the code you have? What specifically do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a small program?

1. 'uigetdir' [http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uigetdir.html] to let user to select the directory where image files are.
2. 'dir' and determine the names of the files in that directory.
3. 'listdlg' to create a list of files on a GUI, with 'SelectionMode' as 'multiple'
4. check the file extension (you can do this before #3 also to show only image files in the list.)
5. count (N) how many image files the user wants to load and plot ('length' of the selected filename string).
6. loop for N times and go through the list of filenames, and open each one with the appropriate loader function (by determining the file extension of each file before loading)
7. as you load the data from the files, you can plot them however you like either in a single figure or multiple.

Best,
Y.T.