# matlab code source

Tags: matlab

how to write a program in matlab that reads a certain number of images let's say 20 for example which are  saved in a given directory (C:) such that later i can use them. suppose that the images are saved by numbers. later, i am gonna use them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you seen the documentation for e.g. `imread()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading multiple images in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the code look something like this. Assuming cell array im holds your images.

Write out:

```
IMG_DIR = 'C:\';
filename_root = 'image';
IMG_EXT = '.jpg';

NUM_IMAGES = 20;

for i = 1:NUM_IMAGES
   imwrite(im{i}, [IMG_DIR filename_root num2str(i) IMG_EXT]); 
end
```

Read in:

```
for i = 1:NUM_IMAGES
   im{i} = imread([IMG_DIR filename_root num2str(i) IMG_EXT]); 
end
```

If you don't know how many there are, you can also use ls command (works differently in Windows vs. Linux).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, in advance, which files will be in there, but you know that they have the string in them, `'rawImage'` (like `'rawImage001.jpg'` etc.) you can do something like

```
a = dir('c:\temp');
requiredBaseFileName = 'rawImage';  % you want them to contain the substring 'rawImage'

for i = 1:length(a),

     fileName = a(i).name;

     if(isempty(strfind(fileName,'.jpg')) & isempty(strfind(fileName,'.png')))
           continue;
     end


     if(isempty(strfind(fileName,requiredBaseFileName)))
           continue;
     end
     % do your processing here

end
```