# How can I retrieve images from a cell array in a MAT-file?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, psychtoolbox

I have used the following code to get multiple (64) images into a MAT-file:

```
D = dir('*.wav');

wavcell = cell(1,numel(D));

for i = 1:numel(D)

  wavcell{i} = wavread(D(i).name);

end
```

However, I now can't retrieve the images from any of the matrices I have in this MAT-file. It contains a 64x1 structure array (`D`), a 1x64 cell array (`imcell`) and an array with one number in it (64) (`i`).

I need to be able to access individual images in the cell array for use in a psychtoolbox experiment.

Any help would be GRATEFULLY received!!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I'm seeing: you're loading WAV files, which are *audio* files, not *image* files. You should first try to remedy this situation.

Once you're sure that you're loading the right type of data (i.e. images), you can get the data back out of the MAT-file you create in a number of ways with the [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) command:

```
load('your_file.mat');           %# Loads all the variables in the file
%# OR
load('your_file.mat','imcell');  %# Loads just the variable imcell
```

Now you will have a variable in the local workspace called `imcell` which will be a cell array of image data. To [index the *contents* of the cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108), you would use curly braces `{}` like so:

```
image1 = imcell{1};  %# Place the contents of the first cell into image1
```

Comment: Given that the OP is using wavread, it seems reasonable to assume that the only mistake being made is that they are referring to the audio data as images?

Comment: @mutzmatron: Before posting this question, the OP had first posted it as an answer to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab) (now deleted) where they were using IMREAD, so I can't be sure which they want to do.