# Reading images from folder one by one

Tags: matlab

I have a folder that has various images I am trying to read images in a loop from folder one by one using imread command, any suggestion how to do it best 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading multiple images in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to synchronize your image names to read in a loop. They have to be like `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, `image3.jpg`... You have 10 images like this.

```
NumberOfimages=10;       %chose the number of images you want to give input
prefix_image='image';    %change the desired input image name here only
fileformat='.jpg';       %change the desired input image format here only

for num=1:NumberOfimages
  image = imread(strcat(prefix_image,num2str(num),fileformat));
end
```

Comment: Please don't put a signature in your posts. See the [faq#signatures].

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) function to get all files inside a directory. This will return a vector of structs which also includes the filenames
- loop over all structs
- check if file is an image (check e.g. extension)
- read image

Answer (score 0):

well this function will help you to read many images at once even with diferent names:

First put all your images in a folder for example: D:/lab/

they must be in the same format for example: tif

to call the function you type :

```
A=imread_many(  );
```

and all the images will be in the variable A

if you want the first image you type `A{1}`  if u want the second u type `A{2}`   ..etc

```
function [ A ] = imread_many(  )

  srcFiles = dir('D:\lab\*.tif');  % the folder in which ur images exists
 for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('D:\lab\',srcFiles(i).name);
    A{i} = imread(filename);
    figure, imshow(A{i});
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\Omm\Downloads\multicharacterrec\*.png');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\Omm\Downloads\multicharacterrec\',srcFiles(i).name);
    I = imread(filename);
    figure, imshow(I);
```

Answer (score -1):

This can Help !

```
S = struct2cell(dir('*.jpg'));
FileNames = S(1,:);
lenDb = length(FileNames);

result= struct('img', {});

for j = 1 : lenDb


    result(j).img = imread(FileNames{j})
end
```

All the images are in struct "result.img"

To have access just call result(NUM).img

Ex:

image(result(1).img)