# Issue in using xlswrite command in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have to run my code for multiple images and compare the outputs of all the images. For running multiple images I have followed the idea give in this link: [Loading multiple images in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab)

It is working fine. Now, I have to export the results of all the images to a excel file. For this purpose, I am using xlswrite command in MATLAB. The issue I am facing is that the outputs are overwritten on the same location in the excel file so at the end of simulation I have only one output saved in the excel file. After writing the results of first image in the excel file, the results of next images should be written in the next location and so on for all the images. I am unable to do so. Please help me with this.

### Code that I have used:

```
ex = {'IDR', 'CAR', 'PSNRN', 'psnr'; IDR CAR psnrn psnr}

xlswrite('output.xls', ex, 'SBF', 'E1');
```

### Last five lines of my code:

```
mse=kk/(m*n);
psnr=10*(log10((double(255*255))/mse));

display(psnrn);
display(psnr);

ex = {'IDR', 'CAR', 'PSNRN', 'psnr'; IDR CAR psnrn psnr}

xlswrite('output.xls', ex, 'SBF', 'E1');

end
```

If required, I will provide my full code. Please help, I am new to MATLAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's always writing to the same location is that you always supply it with the same cell reference `'E1'`. You need to either use a specialised xls appending script, as suggested by the OP, or change your cell reference in the loop, or write the whole lot at once.

**Examples:**

Write in a loop:

```
xlStartColStr = 'E';
xlStartRow = 1;
for myIndex = 1:something
    % Do your stuff...

    try
        ex = {...};
        xlStartRow = myIndex;
        cellRef = [xlStartColStr num2str(xlStartRow)];
        xlswrite('output.xls', ex, 'SBF', cellRef);
    catch err
        error([mfilename ':ErrorSavingFile'], ...
            'Could not save file for image %g : %s', myIndex, err.message);
    end
end
```

Or write all at once:

```
allMyData = {};
for myIndex = 1:something
    % Do your stuff...

    ex = {...};
    allMyData = [allMyData; ex];
end

cellRef = 'E1';
try
    xlswrite('output.xls', allMyData, 'SBF', cellRef);
catch err
    error([mfilename ':ErrorSavingFile'], ...
        'Could not save file for images : %s', err.message);
end
```

The `try...catch` in the loop version is to give you extra information should something fail, but it's still a good idea to do this in the non-looped version, so I have included it there too. The first method is capable of saving some of the data, even if the rest is not in a valid for `xlsread` (just change the error to a warning, or some kind of log message), but will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28600-xlsappend)

Another option is to append to the data and call `xlswrite` once outside the loop.