# run matlab script that process series of images in visual studio(c# language)?

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio-2012

using following Matlab code I have successfully load the images in folder (location:F:\anuradha)
but when it is run through visual studio (c# language) results were not obtained.
can anyone help me????

```
%code_01
filePattern1 = fullfile('F:\anuradha\', '*.jpg');
    imagefiles1 = dir(filePattern1);
```

it should be mention here I have create object in C# and the matlab script is passed in to string the following code gives more explanation

```
string mScript;
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
      private void loadMScript_segment()
      {

            System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
                        new System.IO.StreamReader("F:\\anuradha\\resizeing.m");

            mScript = myFile.ReadToEnd();

            myFile.Close();
        }
        private void buttonsgmnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadMScript_segment();
            matlab.Execute(mScript);
        }
```

here resizeing.m is the matlab script which is included ***code_01*** mention above

here it is not the case of execution pattern. it gives error at the matlab script, which is mention below,

```
%resizeing.m
 filePattern1 = fullfile('F:\anuradha\', '*.jpg');
 imagefiles1 = dir(filePattern1);
 imagefiles1 = dir(filePattern1);
 nfiles1 = length(imagefiles1);
 for jj=1:nfiles1
    currentfilename1 = imagefiles1(jj).name;
    currentimage1 = imread(currentfilename1);
    images{jj} = currentimage1; 
    b = currentimage1;
    figure;
    imshow(b);
    hold on;
 end
```

*according to the above code it should be display all image inside the folder after run the c# code*

Comment: Can you show the C# code that you used to execute this?

Comment: the following link resolve it. thanks for writer. [this document helps me to end with best results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408112/loading-multiple-images-in-matlab)